# How to run loop inside python to run AWS CLI?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, while-loop, do-while

I have a basic JSON file with multiple key-value pairs. I want to parse a values from JSON and run AWS command to create SSM Parameter store.

How to add looping so that my cmd will take each name and each value from JSON and create each parameter store.

Parameter JSON:

```
{
  "Name" : "Account Summary",
  "Value" : "/some/values/to/be/there"
  "Name" : "Account Investment"
  "Value" : "/some/other/values/here"
}
```

Python script:

```
with open("parameters.json") as f:
   baselist = json.load(f)
   for key, value in baselist.items():
       aws ssm put-parameter --name "" --type "String" --value ""
```

Comment: can you confirm the json format?  usually there is a record separater there that splits a name/value pair.  like this `[{ "Name": "Account Summary", "Value":"/some values/"},{ "Name": "Account Summary", "Value":"/some values/"},{ "Name": "Account Summary", "Value":"/some values/"}]`.  can you confirm that?  Thanks

Comment: This is invalid JSON format just like @arcee123 said.

Comment: sorry my fault, the correct format is this: ```[{ "Name": "Account Summary", "Value":"/TRSWeb/TRS/"},{ "Name": "Placeholder", "Value":"/TRSWeb/TRS/Retirement/"},{ "Name": "Transaction History", "Value":"/TRSWeb/TRS/Retirement/Gateway/"}]```

Comment: can you help how do i loop in my command so that i can iterate each name-value pair

Comment: Go with pure python solution and use boto3 https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html in order to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the valid format of JSON for what you're looking for

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Account Summary",
        "Value": "/some/values/to/be/there"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Account Investment",
        "Value": "/some/other/values/here"
    }
]
```

And your loop would look something like this:

```py
import json
ssm=[
     {
         "Name": "Account Summary",
         "Value": "/some/values/to/be/there"
     },
     {
         "Name": "Account Investment",
         "Value": "/some/other/values/here"
     }
 ]


for i in ssm:
     print(f"aws ssm put-parameter --name \"{i.get('Name')}\" --type \"String\" --value  \"{i.get('Value')}\"")
```

The output would look something like this:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name "Account Summary" --type "String" --value  "/some/values/to/be/there"
aws ssm put-parameter --name "Account Investment" --type "String" --value  "/some/other/values/here"
```

> **I do NOT recommend to use AWS like this! This can be very error-prone and takes a lot of the features away since you would require run this as subcommand**

You should instead use the [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) Python SDK provided by AWS for these sort of things. This is the recommended way of accessing AWS resources on scripts.

This is a sample code snippet from the documentation for the same `put-parameter`:

```py
response = client.put_parameter(
    Name='string',
    Description='string',
    Value='string',
    Type='String'|'StringList'|'SecureString',
    KeyId='string',
    Overwrite=True|False,
    AllowedPattern='string',
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    Tier='Standard'|'Advanced'|'Intelligent-Tiering',
    Policies='string',
    DataType='string'
)
```

As you can see it has more features and you can sanity-check the response much more effectively as this would throw actual Python exceptions that can be checked on the script

Comment: Thanks Praveen, i even first tried with Boto3 but i am not sure how to use loop in SDK to parse multiple values from JSON file above.

Comment: When you say multiple values. Do you mean creating multiple SSM parameters? Or one SSM parameter with multiple values in the value field?